# Moniter form validity from inside the controller

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form laid out..i want to watch for its validity from inside the controller so that i can change a few model values and call a function

```js
 $scope.$watch('address',function(){
      console.log(address.$valid);
});
```

```html
<form name="address">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-100">
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Address1</span>
          <input type="text" name="address.addr1" ng-model="addr.addr1"  required>
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I have tried attaching the $scope to my form name.It throws an error saying "cannot find property $valid of the undefined."
And currently this one throws undefined

Comment: it should be  `$scope.$watch('address',function(newVal){
      console.log(newVal && newVal.$valid);
});` or just have `$scope.address.$valid` instead of `address.$valid`

Comment: look at the note below i said i have tried attaching $scope but it did not work

Comment: when i console.log ($scope.address.$valid) it throws an error " Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined" ...Simply doing a console.log(address) gives me the HTML code for the form

Comment: `$scope` would not have form `address`on initial watch fire, you should try the suggested first way

Comment: not helping bruv...still throws an undefined

Comment: It would be great if you can share fiddle/plunkr with problem statement

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/4U2xdytDgrj1j46DDHaR?p=preview  problem statement is same as above i want to know asynchronously if my form got validated or not and depending on it i want to set few models and execute a function...

Answer (score 0):

You can watch function returning value:

```
$scope.watch(function() {
  return $scope.address.$valid;
}, function() {
  console.log($scope.address.$valid);
});
```

Comment: are you sure because this gives me an error saying $scope.$watch is not a function

Comment: Of course I'm sure, I wouldn't have posted it if I was not sure. Did you inject $scope?

Comment: Setup angular application properly and it will work. What's the point in loading angular 2, if you have angular 1 app. And it's `$watch`, not "watch".